# Style a list in css to display inline

Tags: html, css, list

i have a unordered list that displays a link and an image, and i want to display them inline.  i have used the following:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link one</a>
<li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link two</a>
<li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link three</a>
</ul>
```

in the css i have put:

```
li {
display: inline;
margin: 0 10px;
}
```

but the list is still showing one item per line

Comment: have you seen how much space a list item takes ?

Comment: I think as the image size is big so comes like one item per line

Answer (score 1):

Close the `li` tags

```
<style>
    li {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
    }
    </style>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link three</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer was to change it to display: inline-block;

hope this helps others.

Comment: inline and inline-block gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

**Close your li's and use , its working as expected**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link one</a></li>
<li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link two</a></li>
<li><a href="www."><img src="www."/>Link three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li {
float: left;
width: 100px; /*your width*/
margin: 0 10px;
}
```